# If an operator has a cyclic vector, then its co-rank is at most $1$

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

Prove that if an operator on a Hilbert space has a cyclic vector, then its co-rank is at most $1$.

My attempt:

If an operator $T$ on Hilbert space $H$ has cyclic vector $u$, and $v \in$ $(TH)^\perp$,
write $v=c_0u+c_1Tu+...$

If $u, Tu, T^2u, ...$ are pairwise orthogonal, then I can get $v=c_0u$, hence the co-rank of $T$ is at most $1$.

But in general, I don't know how to show it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Let $P$ be the orthogonal projection onto the closed span of $\{Tu,T^2u,T^3u,\ldots\}$.  If $x=u-Pu$, then $x$ is orthogonal to $PH$, and $u$ is in the closed span of $\{x,Tu,T^2u,T^3u,\ldots\}$, which therefore is all of $H$.    Because $x$ is orthogonal to $PH$ and $H$ is spanned by $\{x\}\cup\{Tu,T^2u,\ldots\}$, it follows that $H$ is the orthogonal internal direct sum $H=\mathbb Cx\oplus PH$.  Note that $(TH)^\perp\subseteq (PH)^\perp=\mathbb C x$, which is $0$ or $1$ dimensional depending on whether or not $x=0$.

Comment: Thank you so much, your answer is very clear.